# Bootstarp navbar

Tags: python, django, templates, bootstrap-4

I don't really know much about the frontend, because I work mostly with the backend in python, but for my project I still need some kind of frontend to display data in my template, so I used bootstrap (version 4.1), please tell me how I can place the search field in the center of the navigation bar, and move the profile section to the end of the right side of the navigation bar. Example html and a screenshot of the navigation bar below

```
{% load static %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="height: 100px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="{% static 'home/logos/fishing_logo.svg' %}" alt="logo" width="120" height="100">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">
        Home <img src="{% static 'home/logos/house_logo.svg' %}" alt="logo" width="15" height="15" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">News</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">How to catch</a>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Profile
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log in</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registration</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View profile</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To center a navbar item, you can use `"text-center"` This will center aligned text on all viewport sizes. To place the search field in the center of the navigation bar, do something like this:

```
      <form class="d-flex text-center" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
```

See [Text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/).

To move the profile section to the end of the right side of the navigation bar, use the ml-auto class:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Profile</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log in</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registration</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View profile</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
```

See [Auto margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).